# What is a component of an REST API called?

Tags: rest, api, terminology

Is there a name for one piece of an API?

For example, say I have an API the offers four services:

```
getCustomerInfo
setCustomerInfo
getProductInfo
setProductInfo
```

Then say, I want to tell a colleague:

> The API is going to need a fifth webhook?

I know this is an incorrect use of the word webhook.

What is the correct terminology? 
Thanks!

UPDATE: This might be a duplicate. krishna kanth's answer here: [What is an Endpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45348979/6036221) is:

> The term Endpoint was initially used for WCF services. Later even
>   though this word is being used synonymous to API resources, REST
>   recommends to call these URI (URI[s] which understand HTTP verbs and
>   follow REST architecture) as "Resource".
>
> In a nutshell, a Resource or Endpoint is kind of an entry point to a
>   remotely hosted application which lets the users to communicate to it
>   via HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the word you're looking for is resource. I also think that getting and setting would be combined under a single resource and the HTTP calls to that resource would define whether you are GETing or PUTing (setting in REST using HTTP).

Answer (score 2):

I think in general an API is a set of methods of communication between various software components.

So, I would say:
The API is going to need a fifth method?

Wikipedia also defines API and methods here: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface

Comment: Coming from a WebAPI background I like `method` as well.  I tend to group my REST APIs into nouns (grouping concept; controller) and verbs (methods of nouns/controllers).

Answer (score 1):

Roy Thomas Fielding defines it as **Resource Identifier** in your dissertation for the degree of Doctor of Philosophy (see [Architectural Styles and the Design of Network-based Software Architectures](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/fielding_dissertation.pdf)).

According Roy Fielding:

> REST uses a **resource identifier** to identify the particular resource 
>   involved in an interaction between components.

I believe you can use the resource identifier `/product` do handle the `product` resource and the resource identifier `/customer` to handle the `customer` resource. Also, use the appropriated HTTP method to do the desired action. For example:

- PUT to `/product/{id}` to edit a `product` resource identified by `{id}` (instead of `setProductInfo`)
- GET to `/product/{id}` to return a representation of a `product` resource identified by `{id}` (instead of `getProductInfo`)